# How can I get string values out of an ABPersonRef / ABPerson?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

This question arose while using `[PKPayment billingAddress]`, which is listed as type `ABRecordRef` (but to be more precise, is of type `ABPersonRef`).

Comment: The "Address Book Programming Guide for iOS" tells you how to do this.

Comment: IMO it's opaque and hard to find, and AddressBook's C APIs are inconvenient to use and hard to understand.

Comment: @rmaddy, Is that telling how to get Email and Phone number from Passbook ( Apple Pay). I tried but its nil always :(

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *streetAddress;
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(addressMultiValueRef) > 0) {
    CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressMultiValueRef, 0);
    streetAddress = (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
}

NSString *city;
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(addressMultiValueRef) > 0) {
    CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressMultiValueRef, 0);
    city = (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCityKey);
}

NSString *state;
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(addressMultiValueRef) > 0) {
    CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressMultiValueRef, 0);
    state = (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStateKey);
}

NSString *zip;
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(addressMultiValueRef) > 0) {
    CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressMultiValueRef, 0);
    zip = (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCityKey);
}
```

The same method can be used to get the `kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey` and `kABPersonAddressCountryKey` properties as well.

Don't forget to link against the `AddressBook` framework and `#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>`

Comment: How can I get values like Email , Phone number etc from Passbook (Apple Pay) ?